# Freezes on HP Laptop, getting worse

Tags: windows-10, laptop, freeze

I have here a HP ZBook with Windows 10. A week ago he started to randomly freeze when we work with it. Freezes means nothing works anymore but you could move the mouse (CTRL+ALT+DEL did not work).

The only error in the events was this one:

```
The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{6B3B8D23-FA8D-40B9-8DBD-B950333E2C52}
and APPID 
{4839DDB7-58C2-48F5-8283-E1D1807D0D7D}
to the user NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE SID (S-1-5-19) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

I did not found much about this error, just that you can provide permission with the tool dcomcnfg. But I did not found the APPID, so we decided to "Reset this PC" with the Windows Recovery Tools.

After the reset and a "clean" Windows the freezes still happens. So i tried to reset the PC over the advanced boot options (F11 -> Troubleshoot -> Reset this PC). Meanwhile the freezes getting worse (more often) and the reset process cant finish without a freeze happens. I let it run over night, it freezed at 28% and never moved on. Now that the freezes also happens in the advanced boot options (F11) is it possible that it is a hardware defect?

What other options do I have to fix this?

Edit: How the system freezes:

So I downloaded hwinfo to monitor the temp. The temp didnt rise much but at one point it stopped to update the temperatorinfos. I was still able to move the windows or select another window for like 15sec. then I was only able to move the one active window anymore for like 15sec and then I could only move the mouse. But after like 3min I couldnt move the mouse anymore. Find this behavior very strange and cant find an explanation.

Comment: If you performed a Reset and you still have the problem, that means your problem, isn't caused by software.  I also presume the PC didn't always freeze.  This means you have a hardware releated event causing the freezes.  The fact the Reset process now fails indicates a storage releated problem.  *Freezes means nothing works anymore but you could move the mouse (CTRL+ALT+DEL did not work).* - also indicates you have issues connected to storage I/O issues.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest running hardware diagnostics on your PC. HP business PC's used to have them built-in & accessible by pressing F9 after power-on. You might also find them in the BIOS. If you can't find anything there you can use something like Ultimate Boot CD to run some diagnostics. You could go to the partition magic linux live item, run gsmartcontrol to run SMART tests on your hard drive which I suspect is the issue. Otherwise run the Windows Memory Diagnostic or memtest on that Ultimate Boot CD

Answer (score 0):

My latop did the same,so i dumped it,and started over.Seems Windows 10,which was loaded on the computer when I bought it got corrupted.Went through a Microsoft tech,and he had me install a thumbdrive,and loaded a new version.Once I loaded this,it cured the problem.